# Access to polygon matrix from json files

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I load polygons from json file using loadGeoJson. In json file I have properties name and id. All Polygons loads correctly on the map.
How can I get matrix of all polygons? I need to check that my point containsLocation of one from this polygons. TIA 4 answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use :

```
var woj =[];
  map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(event) {
  var adm=event.feature.getProperty('id');
  woj.push(adm);
   });
```

That solves my problem.